# SceneKit : update SCNGeometry with dae animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, scenekit

I decided to use SceneKit for an awesome iOS project.
But i found a big issue.

In my application, i load some animated .dae.
It's well displayed. But the SCNGeometry of the node don't update, during the animation.
I tried to check the presentationNode, but still the same.
How can i get the updated value of the geometry ? Like vector.

Comment: What are you trying to animate?

Comment: Also, this question looks very similar to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29533199/608157)

Comment: not exactly because now the animation is inside the dae file.

Comment: Ok. What is the animation doing? (also, some code of how you get the animation from the .dae file and how you apply it will probably help)

Comment: i load my scene : SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"attack.dae"]; the animation is in the dae file.

Comment: Instead of posting a comment, you should *edit* your question and provide the additional information.

Comment: Ok. So that's how you load the scene. How do you get hold of the animation? Are you referencing it by key? What is the animation supposed to do? How do you add the animation? To what object (the node or the geometry) are you adding the animation?

Answer (score 0):

That is how I can do it:

```
SCNNode * mainNode = [[SCNNode alloc]init];
SCNScene * scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:sceneNamed inDirectory:some/path/where/you/have/it options:nil];

for (SCNNode * node in [scene.rootNode childNodes]) {
    [mainNode addChildNode: node];
}
```

It should work in most cases if your DAE file contains animations.